# query and select function with table to detect the time stamp for deferent column and send with json

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a table contains punch of strings and these strings show if led ON or OFF, also i have used time stamp to detect time when the led was ON, check my table below.

[image]

I have successfully detected when the tp12 is on and showed the timestamp for that column using this

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM plate WHERE tp12 REGEXP "L13_ON" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1');

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
print json_encode($data);
```

so this code only be able to show the led state for tp12 with time stamp but I want to know when led is ON for all tp13 and tp14 with time stamp and then get them using ajax from different file

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
       url: "plate.php",
       method:"GET",
        dataType:"JSON",
       success: function (data) {
           var id = [];                       
           var tp12 = [];
           var dateandtime = [];
           for (var i in data){                  
              //var time = ((data[i].Datee +  data[i].Time));
              var timestam = (new Date(data[i].dateandtime));
              console.log(timestam);
              console.log(data[i].id);
              console.log(data[i].tp); 
                var timeEnd = new Date();
                var diff = (timeEnd - timestam) / 60000; //dividing by seconds and milliseconds
                var minutes = (diff % 60);
                var hours = Math.floor((diff - minutes) / 60);
                console.log((hours+":"+minutes.toFixed(0))); 
                document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = (hours+":"+minutes.toFixed(0));
          }                             
                   
        }
    });
});   },  6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As ling you don't have NULL in your table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE lights (
>   `Id` int,
>   `tpl2` VARCHAR(7),
>   `tpl3` VARCHAR(7),
>   `tpl4` VARCHAR(7),
>   `dateandtime` daTETIME
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO lights
>   (`Id`, `tpl2`, `tpl3`, `tpl4`, `dateandtime`)
> VALUES
>   ('240', 'L13—OFF', 'L14—OFF', 'L15—ON', '2021-10-24 16:31:19'),
>   ('239'  ,'L13—OFF', 'L14—ON', 'L15—OFF',    '2021-10-24 15:30:18'),
>   ('238'  ,'L13—ON', 'L14—OFF', 'L15—OFF',    '2021-10-24 14:28:17'),
>   ('237'  ,'L13—OFF', 'L14—OFF', 'L15—OFF',   '2021-10-24 16:27:16');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM lights WHERE CONCAT_WS('', `tpl2`, `tpl3`, `tpl4`) LIKE '%—ON%'
> ```
>
> ```
>  Id | tpl2      | tpl3      | tpl4      | dateandtime        
> --: | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :------------------
> 240 | L13—OFF | L14—OFF | L15—ON  | 2021-10-24 16:31:19
> 239 | L13—OFF | L14—ON  | L15—OFF | 2021-10-24 15:30:18
> 238 | L13—ON  | L14—OFF | L15—OFF | 2021-10-24 14:28:17
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccb9b165d81ba60e8cdce7f317fbf1aa)*

Comment: ok, here you are detecting the led ON for each column, but can you display what time each row led was ON

Comment: to catch that, and that io snot part of your question, you need a loop, which you could make in a stored procedure in php or javascript